# Do we say “Seek help” or “seek for help”?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrases

Do we add *for* when we say *seek*?

Which of these is correct?

> To seek something

Or...

> To seek for something

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: [Answered on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/241470/194233), but I don't like the explanations.

Comment: You can ask for help, or you can seek help.  You can't seek for help.  But you can look for help and you can seek for something.

Comment: @BruceMurray Are you sure you can "seek _for_ something?" You can "seek _something_ for _someone_" but using any preposition before the thing being sought sounds very wrong to me.

Comment: @Type.  No, I am not. I was distracted.  My apologies,.

Comment: *Seek **for** help* is idiomatic in Indian English only. In other English regions, it's not idiomatic, and would be marked as incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the dictionary entry for ***seek*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seek)), you will not find one example of this verb with the preposition *for*. It is true that people do use *seek for* sometimes mistakenly, but sometimes *[because British English](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/seek)*. There is [proof](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seek%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) that ***seek for*** is British, although the use with *for* is in decline:

[image]

Plus, ***seek for*** is biblical:

> - ***[KJV Romans 2:7](https://biblehub.com/kjv/romans/2-7.htm)*** To them who by patient continuance in well doing ***seek for*** glory and honour and immortality, eternal life.
> - ***[KJV Mark 3:32](https://biblehub.com/mark/3-32.htm)*** Behold, thy mother and thy brethren without ***seek for*** thee.

This site [aimpublishing](http://www.aimpublishing.com/index.php?main_page=document_general_info&products_id=846) says plainly that:

> ***Seek*** is a transitive verb that may mean to try to get something or to try to find something or someone that you need in your life. Please note that ***seek is not followed by the preposition for***.
>
> - Incorrect:  This book is a must read for those who are seeking for the meaning of life.
> - Correct:    This book is a must read for those who are seeking the meaning of life. *(Note that this is a Canadian site)*

A quick look at the etymology of *seek* will explain why some argue that this verb ***contains for in its meaning***:

> From Old English *secan* "inquire, search **for**; pursue; long **for**, wish **for**, desire; look **for**, expect from. ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/seek))

It might help to look at the etymology of *beseech*, too. Although it contains *seek*, we never tend to use *beseech* with *for*:

> c. 1200, *bisecen* "to entreat, beg urgently," from Old English *besecan*; see ***be- + seek***. "In contrast to the simple vb., in which the northern *seek* has displaced the southern *seech*, in the compound beseech has become the standard form" [OED]. ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=beseech))

My conclusion is that although the use of ***seek for*** is regarded as incorrect by many, it is not. It is simply ***outdated*** or ***antiquated***. Shakespeare used it too:

> Wee'l hunt no more to day, nor ***seeke for*** danger (We'll hunt no more today, nor seek for danger) - [Cymbeline](https://shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?WorkId=7&Act=4&Scene=2#139712).

Answer (score 0):

I find both acceptable and would not edit either. “Seek for” is a construct similar to “look for” or “seek out”: the verb is active and is directed at the object by the preposition. Hence we can seek help, seek for help, look for help, seek out help. All are correct, being clear in meaning with no ambiguity.

Comment: -1, see discussion in comments: "seek" is transitive and doesn't take a preposition before the thing being sought (although _seek out_ is correct: this is a phrasal verb with a more nuanced / focused meaning than simply _seek_).

Comment: I suggest it helpful to consider usage, lack of ambiguity, and clarity of meaning rather than to try to define an inappropriately rigid and restricted formality in which we deny the extension of language merely to maintain a grammatical status quo. “Seek” may once have been used only transitively, with a direct object, but “seek for” is now acceptable and this means that “seek” is not as transitive as it once was. Things change.

Comment: Hear, hear! @Anton FTW! Seriously though I completely agree with you. Language has been called "...a city which we are all constructing together, and it is a city whose construction will never be finished." (RW Emerson). I may prefer some of the linguistic status quo I grew up with, but you might a well just sit back and enjoy the scenery, because you're not in the driver's seat on this journey.